# Rails Ajax not displaying the result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have created a new controller, that in future will be responsible only for translating strings for different objects.
Here is the code of the controller:

```
 # frozen_string_literal: true

class Api::TranslationsController < AuthenticatedController
  def translate_string
    @translated_string = GoogleTranslator.translate('hello', 'de')
    render json: {translated_string: @translated_string.to_json}
  end

  helper_method :translate_string

  private

  def translations_params
    params.permit(
      :id,
      :translated_string
    )
  end
end
```

It is placed in directory controllers/api/translations_controller. Here is the part of routes:

```
  namespace :api do
    resource :translations do
      member do
        get 'translate_string'
      end
    end
  end
```

And here is part of my html.erb to call JS function:

```
        <%= image_tag "google-icon.png", id: "google_icon", onclick: "test_transl()",
        remote: true%>
```

And here is my JS code, currently only with Ajax:

```
<script>
  function test_transl(){
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/api/translations/translate_string",
          dataType: "json",
          success:function (result){
              console.log(result)
          }
      })
  }
</script>
```

I expect this ajax code to translate the world 'hello' on German and get value @translated_string - 'hallo' in console but nothing happens except the fact, that the error I got is 'statusText: "parsererror"'. What may be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong with my code. The problem was with fact that I didn't pass sessions token in ajax. So now my ajax code will look like this:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
         "Authorization": "Bearer " + window.sessionToken
      },
      url: "/api/translations/translate_string",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result){
          console.log(result);
       },
     error: function (result){
          console.log(result, this.error)
     }
  })
```

And def from controller like this:

```
  def translate_string
    @translated_string = GoogleTranslator.translate('hello', 'de')
    render json: @translated_string.to_json
  end
```

The output in console is: "hallo".